# How to convert a surface into a solid

Tags: finite-element-method, geometry, mesh, computational-geometry

**Context**

I am interested in converting surfaces into solids (so I can make a 3D mesh out of them using [`ToElementMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToElementMesh.html))

Say I have the following cool surface

```
f[t_] := With[{s = 3 t/2}, {(2 + Cos[s]) Cos[t], (2 + Cos[s]) Sin[t], Sin[s]} - {2, 0, 0}]
v1[t_] := Cross[f'[t], {0, 0, 1}] // Normalize
v2[t_] := Cross[f'[t], v1[t]] // Normalize
g[t_, θ_] := f[t] + (Cos[θ] v1[t] + Sin[θ] v2[t])/2
gr = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate @ g[t, θ], {t, 0, 4 Pi}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
                      Mesh -> None, MaxRecursion -> 4, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];
```

which I pinched from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85675).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question**

> How would like to make a solid out of what is in it?

I have a hint that there is a simple answer to this problem in the 
context of the new computational geometry tools of *Mathematica* 10
but I have not found it.

In some sense I am after the opposite of [`BoundaryMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BoundaryMesh.html)

Comment: Try `DiscretizeGraphics`

Comment: In[491]:= gr // DiscretizeGraphics
Out[491]= EmptyRegion[3];  so its a bit disapointing

Comment: You could convert it to a `ParametricRegion` and then use `ToElementMesh` - some examples are in the documentation, see also the tutorial to element mesh generation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Method 1: Construct mesh elements manually

We can triangulate a periodic quad-lattice on the surface:

```
n = {180, 20};  (* number of points in each direction *)
pts = Table[
   g[4. Pi/n[[1]] t, 2. Pi/ n[[2]] θ], {t, n[[1]]}, {θ, n[[2]]}];

idcs = {{{1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 3}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 3}}};  (* for a diamond pattern *)
tri = 1 +
  Array[Function[quad, quad[[#]] & /@ idcs[[Mod[+##, 2, 1]]]][Tuples[
        {Mod[#1 + {-1, 0}, Dimensions[pts][[1]]],
         Mod[#2 + {-1, 0}, Dimensions[pts][[2]]]}].{Length[First@pts], 1}] &,
       Most@Dimensions[pts]];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"].
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> Flatten[pts, 1],
  "BoundaryElements" -> {TriangleElement[Flatten[tri, 2]]}
  ]

emesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh]
(*
  ElementMesh[{{-4.86396, 1.5}, {-3.32664, 3.32664}, {-1.5, 1.5}},
   {TetrahedronElement["<" 21544 ">"]}]
*)

MeshRegion@emesh
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notes:

`Tuple` generates the indices of the quadrilaterals in each row (`#1) & column (`#2`), wrapping around at the end of the domain to close up the tube:

```
Tuples[{Mod[#1 + {-1, 0}, Dimensions[pts][[1]]],
        Mod[#2 + {-1, 0}, Dimensions[pts][[2]]]}]
```

The dot product with `{Length[First@pts], 1}` converts a `{row, column}` pair to the index of the corresponding point in `pts`.

We triangulate the quadrilaterals by alternating which diagonal is used.  The variable `idcs` contains two lists of two triangles, representing both ways.  The integers themselves are indices of the quadrilateral (given by `Tuples[..].{Length[..], 1}` above).

```
idcs = {{{1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 3}},   (* 1-4 diagonal *)
        {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 3}}};  (* 2-3 diagonal *)
```

---

#### Method 2: Mesh the domain and apply parametrization

This takes more advantage of FEM/ElementMesh capabilities.  First mesh the domain.  Then apply `g` to map domain mesh coordinates onto to the surface.  Use these coordinates and the domain mesh to construct a boundary mesh on the surface.  Finally, use `ToElementMesh` to construct a mesh of the solid.

```
 Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

tscale = 4; θscale = 0.5;                (* scale roughly proportional to speeds *)
dom = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, tscale}, {0, θscale}},         (* domain *)
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.001}];
coords = g[4 Pi #1/tscale, 2 Pi #2/θscale] & @@@ dom["Coordinates"];   (* apply g *)
bmesh2 = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> coords,
   "BoundaryElements" -> dom["MeshElements"]
   ];
emesh2 = ToElementMesh@ bmesh2
(*
  ElementMesh[{{-4.86407, 1.5}, {-3.32362, 3.32362}, {-1.49991, 1.49991}},
   {TetrahedronElement["<" 5581 ">"]}]
*)

MeshRegion@ emesh2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: I thought I would have to glue the boundaries together by hand, but `ToBoundaryMesh` seems to handle it for me. :D

Comment: Thanks! I like method 2 better.

Comment: @MichaelE2...learned such a lot from this +1, of course...thanks :)

Comment: @chris You're welcome.  I like method 2 better, too.  But I came up with it second and after some time had passed.  I was afraid I'd have to remap coordinates & indices to glue the boundaries together.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same thing if there's no known equation of the surface?

Comment: @RunnyKine If the surface is not given by equations, how is it given? (If it's already a valid boundary mesh, then you're in business, aren't you?  If it's self-intersecting, then you're in trouble.  If it's not closed, then perhaps you could stick on a patch. The  `ParametricPlot3D` has the last problem and maybe the first.)

Comment: Thanks. My problem is mainly with self-intersecting regions, but I guess there's no easy way around it.

Comment: What is the easiest way to change this code in order to work with non-closed curve tubes. For example, if the function `f` in the question definitions is `f = BezierFunction[#[[{1, 2, 3}]] & /@ {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 1}}]` and `gr` is `gr = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@g[t, \[Theta]], {t, 0, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}]` .

Comment: @AntonAntonov I don't know about the "easiest" way. Add caps, correct the local coordinate frame for making the tube, reduce diameter of tube so it doesn't self-intersect. It's a little long to fit in a comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qNr2T.png (http://pastebin.com/CMKeppVa) -- A more robust way might be to "integrate" the coordinate frame as `t` moves from `0` to `1`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much for the code! It is what I was looking for. And I will consider the ideas you mention.

Comment: @AntonAntonov You're welcome.  I should have mentioned that I reduced the mesh order to 1, to make it easy to get the caps to fit exactly.  I didn't want to figure out how to make quadratic-order mesh caps. It certainly should be possible.  I mention it in case your end use is to solve a PDE.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have meshes that come by a long route from Blender, through Autodesk's MeshMixer, to me as .OBJ files. MMA's `FindMeshDefects` finds no problems, so MeshMixer does an ostensibly good job. Mathematica's `SolidRegionQ` does not think they're solid, even though other tools find them watertight (e.g., https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh). I'm not sure of the difference between 'watertight' and 'solid', but I wanted to point out a case of ostensibly defect-free surface meshes that aren't solid. I'll probably formulate an MVE and another SE question on this topic.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an attempt to use MichaelE2's method 2 but only using built-in functions with no need to load the `FEM` package.

```
tscale = 4; θscale = 0.5;
domain = DiscretizeRegion[FullRegion[2], {{0, tscale}, {0, θscale}}, 
                          MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.0005}]
coords = g[4 Pi #1/tscale, 2 Pi #2/θscale] & @@@ MeshCoordinates[domain];  
         (* This is the same g defined in the question *)
mr = MeshRegion[coords, MeshCells[domain, 2]];
```

Here is where it gets tricky with built-in functions. I first convert the `MeshRegion` `mr` to a `Graphics3D` object using `Show` then discretize the boundary and finally use `TriangulateMesh` to get a solid. `BoundaryMeshRegion` seems to fail here, hence, the workaround.

```
tm = TriangulateMesh @ BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics @ Show @ mr
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MeshCellCount[tm, 3] > 0    (* check that there are 3D cells *)
```

> True

Comment: Nice! FEM has become a  bit like black magic between undocumented functions, failing ones etc… :-)

Comment: @user21 Why does `BoundaryMeshRegion[coords, MeshCells[domain, 2]]` complain about a boundary not being closed?

Comment: @RunnyKine This is the message I get : BoundaryMeshRegion::bsuncl: "The boundary surface is not closed because the edges Line[{{719,1},{97,719},{1,97}}] only come from a single face."

Comment: @AntonAntonov. I'm guessing you're using a much newer version of *Mathematica*. A lot of things that worked with these region functions in previous versions are now broken. If you check this site you'll see I've found quite a few.

Comment: @RunnyKine Yes, I am using the newest version. Thank you for your clarification. I like that you programmed Michael E2's approach with built-in functions.

Comment: @AntonAntonov. Thanks, I always try to avoid non built-in functions whenever possible.

Comment: I feel this morning FEM deserves a little defense: First FEM is **built-in** (as a standard package); it is, imo, better documented than `Mesh*` functionality; and, this will change no doubt, its reliability, in terms of how often it behaves as documented, has been greater.  OTOH, it's narrower in scope, which limits its usefulness (and is probably connected to its reliability).

Answer (score 6):

For a closed surface such as this one, a slight modification of the function `MakeTriangleMesh[]` in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118559) can be used:

```
MakeTriangleMesh[vl_List, {closedu : (True | False) : False,
                           closedv : (True | False) : False}, opts___] := 
       Module[{dims = Most[Dimensions[vl]], v = vl, idx},
              idx = Partition[Range[Times @@ dims], Last[dims]];
              If[TrueQ[closedu],
                 v = Most[v]; idx = Append[Most[idx], First[idx]]];
              If[TrueQ[closedv],
                 v = Most /@ v; idx = Composition[Append[#, First[#]] &, Most] /@ idx];
              BoundaryMeshRegion[Apply[Join, vl], 
                                 Triangle[Flatten[Apply[{Append[Reverse[#1], Last[#2]], 
                                                         Prepend[#2, First[#1]]} &, 
                                 Partition[idx, {2, 2}, {1, 1}], {2}], 2]], opts]] /;
       ArrayQ[vl, 3]

With[{m = 101, n = 31},
     MakeTriangleMesh[N[Table[Evaluate @ g[t, θ],
                              {t, 0, 4 π, 4 π/(m - 1)}, {θ, 0, 2 π, 2 π/(n - 1)}]],
                      {True, True}]]
```

[image: meshed tube]

Compute the volume:

```
Volume[%]
   24.674785447032324
```