# Can I convert a 2D Region embedded in 3D into a 3D region, filling in the shell?

Tags: regions

Here's a simple example, where there are built-in functions to describe both objects.

```
{shell, ball} = DiscretizeGraphics /@ {Sphere[], Ball[]}
```

[image]

The first of these is a 2D region embedded in 3D, the other is a 3D region.

```
RegionDimension /@ {shell, ball}
RegionEmbeddingDimension /@ {shell, ball}
Area /@ {shell, ball}
Volume /@ {shell, ball}
(* {2, 3} *)
(* {3, 3} *)
(* {12.5066, ∞} *)
(* {0, 4.15297} *)

Show[#, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}] & /@ {shell, ball}
```

[image]

Is there any method to essentially convert the `shell` into the `ball`?  In practice, the `shell` would come from discretizing a `Plot3D` or some other type of method, and I want to create a filled object from that `shell`

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85691/how-to-convert-a-surface-into-a-solid/88711?noredirect=1#comment303741_88711)?

Comment: @RunnyKine - sometimes you just can't come up with the right search terms.  I'll delete, or close as duplicate.  `TriangulateMesh@BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@Sphere[]` is the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the titles don't tell you the real story. :)

Comment: I'll leave it up for others' future searches, but chris's title is pretty accurate description of what I'm trying to do here

Comment: @RunnyKine - I can't get this method to work on the more complicated example I'm trying, but it's too localized I think for a post here.  I put the code in the chatroom if you could look at it

Comment: Did you see my message in chat?

Comment: @RunnyKine I did, haven't had time to digest yet (its amazing how long it takes to get three kids to bed lol). Thanks for putting in so much work, I had thought of your alpha shape function but didn't know there was a3D version. Is a lot of effort to get the volume available to graze in for a goat in space tethered to a spherical silo :-)

Comment: Hope you succeeded in putting the kids to bed :). Yeah, there's a 3D version of it, I posted it long before the 2D one you found. I actually have a more general one that handles both 2D and 3D depending on the input data.