# The Disc and Washer Methods

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, graphics3d, rotation

How is it possible to demonstrate a visual solid of revolution utilizing the washer method?

For example to show the shape formed by rotating the region bounded by $y=(x-2)^4, 8x-y=16$ about $x=10$?

I'm interested in how this sort of task is verified on *Mathematica* if it is possible visually at an algebraic and graphical sense.

Hints as to the necessary coding would be much appreciated, thank you in advance for taking the time to try to help.

Comment: Have you looked at `RevolutionPlot3D[]` already?

Comment: I was under the impression that disk and washer methods were used to find the **volume** of a solid of rotation.  MMA can generate the solid you describe graphically ([here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eDIjC.gif) is the example you describe), but it won't find the volume automatically - that is you still need to set up the correct integral.

Comment: [Several examples on the demonstrations site](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=disk+method+site:demonstrations.wolfram.com&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a symbolic-algebraic way, based on the cylindrical algebraic decomposition (CAD) that `Reduce` computes.

```
(* Disk/Washer method *)
Clear[x, y, z];
eqns = {y == (x - 2)^4, 8 x - y == 16};
axis = x == 10;
{depV} = Variables[Subtract @@ axis];
{indepV} = Complement[{x, y}, {depV}];
vars = {indepV, depV};
components = Map[
   Reduce[#, vars] &,     (* compute CAD *)
   MapThread[               (* construct divisions of the plane by the curves *)
      ReplaceAll,           (* replace == by  all combinations of <, > *)
      {eqns, 
       Thread[Equal -> #]}] & /@ Tuples[{Less, Greater}, Length@eqns]
   ];
(* compute bounds and pick out bounded components *)
bounds = RegionBounds@ImplicitRegion[#, Evaluate@vars] & /@ components;
bounded = Pick[components, FreeQ[#, DirectedInfinity] & /@ bounds];
bounds = Pick[bounds, FreeQ[#, DirectedInfinity] & /@ bounds];
(* check axis does not intersect interior *)
v0 = depV /. First@Solve[axis, depV];
If[bounds[[1, -1, 1]] < v0 < bounds[[1, -1, 2]],
  Print["Warning: axis passes through region."]];
(* construct solid of revolution description *)
solid = bounded /. ineq : (h_)[v1_, r1___, depV, r2___, v2_] :>
    If[v0 <= bounds[[1, -1, 1]],                      (* check which side *)
     h[v1 - v0, r1, Sqrt[(depV - v0)^2 + z^2], r2, v2 - v0],
     h[v0 - v2, r2, Sqrt[(depV - v0)^2 + z^2], r1, v0 - v1]];
(* set up volume integral(s) *)
integrals = bounded /. 
  HoldPattern[_[a_, ___, b_] && _[v1_, ___, v2_]] :> 
   Sign[((v1 - v0)^2 - (v2 - v0)^2) /. indepV -> Mean[N@{a, b}]] *
    Inactive[Integrate][Pi ((v1 - v0)^2 - (v2 - v0)^2), {indepV, a, b}]
(* compute the integral(s) *)
volume = integrals // Activate // Total
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's the Cartesian description of the solid of revolution:

```
solid
(*
  {0 < y < 16 && 
    10 - Root[16 - y - 32 #1 + 24 #1^2 - 8 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 2] < 
     Sqrt[(-10 + x)^2 + z^2] < 10 + 1/8 (-16 - y)}
*)
```

To visualize the solid, it's better to use [`RevolutionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RevolutionPlot3D.html), but here's what happens when you do a straightforward Cartesian `RegionPlot3D`:

```
maxR = Max[Abs[v0 - bounds[[1, -1]]]] + 0.1;
RegionPlot3D[First@solid,
 {x, v0 - maxR, v0 + maxR}, {y, 0, 16.1}, {z, -maxR, +maxR},
 PlotPoints -> 50, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great!  Now how can I turn this into a solid `MeshRegion` so I can find the volume numerically?  :-D

Comment: @JasonB For a numerical solution, I would replace `Integrate` by `NIntegrate`.  For a region-based solution, I've found (so far) that mesh utilities seem to lack sufficient robustness to handle all cases.  I can apply `Discretize@Normal@plot` to this plot and get a mesh region, but `Volume` returns `0`.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to make a plot of the region in question, this is good

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{{x, (x + 8)^4}, {x, 8 x + 64}}, {x, -8, -6}, {th, 0,
   2 π}, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But try as I might, I can't seem to find a way to get the volume of the region using `Volume` - this would involve turning the surface generated above into a closed `Region`.  I've tried the method listed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88711/9490), but the command

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{{x, (x + 8)^4}, {x, 8 x + 64}}, {x, -8, -6}, {th, 0,
     2 π}] // Normal // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics
```

causes a kernel crash.

Comment: I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xjEy5.png) with `DiscretizeGraphics`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Right, but that is just the shell, a 2D region embedded in 3D space.  So if you try to ask for the `Volume` it will give zero.  Now it clearly seems to be a closed region so you ought to be able to convert it to a filled region by first making a boundary and then filling it, but it fails. I just wanted to show that the Region result matched the analytic result, tried to do this for the goat problem, but it failed there too

Comment: D'oh!  Silly me,  I just saw it as what I wanted to see.