# NDEigensystem works for 3D Schrödinger equation but not 4D

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, physics

`NDEigensystem` works fine for the following 3D Schrödinger equation

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Rcube = ImplicitRegion[-1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1 && -1 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}]; 

NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + Boole[x + y + z > -2]*u[x, y, z], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True]}, u, 
  Element[{x, y, z}, Rcube], 3]
```

But when it is generalized to 4D as follows

```
Rcube = ImplicitRegion[-1 <= w <= 1 && -1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1 && -1 <= z <= 1, 
         {w, x, y, z}]; 

NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[w, x, y, z], {w, x, y, z}] + 
  Boole[w + x + y + z > -2]*u[w, x, y, z], 
  DirichletCondition[u[w, x, y, z] == 0, True]}, u, 
  Element[{w, x, y, z}, Rcube], 3]
```

it fails. Why?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I think FEM is the basis for `NDEigensystem` and it is restricted currently to dimensions 1, 2, and 3 -- see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1928222731

Comment: Might be possible to follow this post and do it by hand? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84726/numerically-solving-helmholtz-equation-in-3d-for-arbitrary-shapes