# Specific numerical eigenfunctions of Helmholtz equation in 3D for ellipsoids

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method

I am trying to compute the eigenfunctions of an oblate spheroid (a=75 cm and b=60 cm) using Mathematica's FEM package and Chris' answer from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84726/numerically-solving-helmholtz-equation-in-3d-for-arbitrary-shapes). Specifically, I am looking for eigenfrequencies around 433, 893, 913 and 2400 MGHz. Is there any way I could narrow my search besides getting all eigenfrequencies initially and then looking for the desired outcome which is impractical?

Here is my code for the first 4 eigenmodes:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

helmholzSolve3D[g_, numEigenToCompute_Integer, 
opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
Module[{u, x, y, z, t, pde, dirichletCondition, mesh, boundaryMesh, 
nr, state, femdata, initBCs, methodData, initCoeffs, vd, sd, 
discretePDE, discreteBCs, load, stiffness, damping, pos, nDiri, 
numEigen, res, eigenValues, eigenVectors, 
evIF},

(*Discretize the region*)

If[Head[g] === ImplicitRegion || Head[g] === ParametricRegion, 
mesh = ToElementMesh[DiscretizeRegion[g, opts], opts], 
mesh = ToElementMesh[DiscretizeGraphics[g, opts], opts]];
boundaryMesh = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh];

(*Set up the PDE and boundary condition*)

pde = D[u[t, x, y, z], t] - Laplacian[u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + 
u[t, x, y, z] == 0;
dirichletCondition = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y, z] == 0, True];
(*Pre-process the equations to obtain the FiniteElementData in \
StateData*)nr = ToNumericalRegion[mesh];
{state} = 
NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{pde, dirichletCondition, 
u[0, x, y, z] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 1}, Element[{x, y, z}, nr]];
femdata = state["FiniteElementData"];
initBCs = femdata["BoundaryConditionData"];
methodData = femdata["FEMMethodData"];
initCoeffs = femdata["PDECoefficientData"];

(*Set up the solution*)vd = methodData["VariableData"];

sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space" -> nr, "Time" -> 0.}];

(*Discretize the PDE and boundary conditions*)

discretePDE = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd];
discreteBCs = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[initBCs, methodData, sd];

(*Extract the relevant matrices and deploy the boundary conditions*)

load = discretePDE["LoadVector"];
stiffness = discretePDE["StiffnessMatrix"];
damping = discretePDE["DampingMatrix"];
DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness, damping}, discreteBCs];

(*Set the number of eigenvalues ignoring the Dirichlet positions*)

pos = discreteBCs["DirichletMatrix"]["NonzeroPositions"][[All, 2]];
nDiri = Length[pos];
numEigen = numEigenToCompute + nDiri;

(*Solve the eigensystem*)

res = Eigensystem[{stiffness, damping}, -numEigen];
res = Reverse /@ res;
eigenValues = res[[1, nDiri + 1 ;; Abs[numEigen]]];
eigenVectors = res[[2, nDiri + 1 ;; Abs[numEigen]]];
evIF = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, #] & /@ eigenVectors;

(*Return the relevant information*)

{eigenValues, evIF, mesh}]

{ev, if, mesh} = 
helmholzSolve3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {0.75, 0.6, 0.6}], 4, 
MaxCellMeasure -> 0.025]

Table[
DensityPlot[
if[[i]][x, y, 0.1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2/0.75^2 + y^2/0.6^2 < 1],
PlotLabel -> ev[i] ,
ColorFunction -> Hue,
PlotLegends -> Automatic
],
{i, 1, 4}
]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

You could use something like this:

```
{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + u[x, y, z], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True]}, u, 
  Element[{x, y, z}, Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {0.75, 0.6, 0.6}]], 4, 
  Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> {"FEAST", "Interval" -> {425, 500}}}]

{{427.961, 428.783, 430.026, 430.156},...}
```

And here are the density plots:

```
Table[DensityPlot[funs[[i]][x, y, 0.1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2/0.75^2 + y^2/0.6^2 < 1], 
  PlotLabel -> vals[[i]], ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, 4}]
```

[image]

Slice density plots:

```
Table[SliceDensityPlot3D[funs[[i]][x, y, z], 
  Element[ {x, y, z}, Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {0.75, 0.6, 0.6}]], 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> vals[[i]], 
  PlotTheme -> "Minimal"], {i, Length[vals]}]
```

[image]

And density plots:

```
Table[DensityPlot3D[funs[[i]][x, y, z], 
  Element[ {x, y, z}, Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {0.75, 0.6, 0.6}]], 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> vals[[i]], 
  PlotTheme -> "Minimal"], {i, Length[vals]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to clarify something technical here. Does NDEigensystems compute eigenmodes from start, ie 0 and then narrows its search to the desired interval (425, 500 HZ here)  or does it start from 425 Hz and then stops at 500 Hz?

Comment: @GeorgeGiannoulis, I think the latter, but you could have a [look at the FEAST algorithm](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/~polizzi/feast/).Thought that version is not the same as the one linked in Mathematica but that shlould not matter.  `NDEigensystem` makes use if `Eigensystem` (like in your code)  which then uses FEAST from a library.

Comment: OK one last thing here. I can't seem to understand what the boubdary is in your code. Is it a cube,a sphere, an ellispoid? Something else?

Comment: @GeorgeGiannoulis, it's the ellipsoidI have updated the code.

Comment: Great! I d like to add some density plots though for the eigenvalues. My code looks something like this:

Comment: Table[DensityPlot3D[
  funs[[i]], {x, y, z} \[Element] Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {0.75, 0.6, 0.6}],
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> vals[[i]], . 
  PlotTheme -> "Minimal"], {i, Length[vals]}] However, I get the message that "Ellipsoid[{0,0,0},{0.75,0.6,0.6}] does not have a valid dimension as \
a plotting domain". Any ideas?

Comment: @GeorgeGiannoulis, What version are you using?

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica 11.2

Comment: @GeorgeGiannoulis See update, you need to use `funs[[i]][x, y, z]` not `funs[[i]]`

Comment: So far so good! Can you also change dirichlet boundary condition to neumann (0 on the surface)?

Comment: @GeorgeGiannoulis, sure, just remove the `DirichletCondition`  You could read up on this in the documentation of `NeumannValue`.

Answer (score 6):

You may try `Eigensystem` with

```
Method -> {"FEAST", "Interval" -> {a, b}}
```

to search eigenvalue pairs within an interval. See the documentation of `Eigensystem`, Section "Methods", Subsection "FEAST" for more details.