# Collecting functions and their derivatives on a particular side of a separable differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I'm trying to use Mathematica to solve various separable differential equations, but I'm trying to do this **step-by-step** - *this is important*! I am sort-of making notes to remind me how to do stuff, and the more that I expose the better I remember it. I know about DSolve[], and it works very well, but I want to expose certain internal steps in the process.

Following is an example, using polar co-ordinates in the plane, and the wave equation, but what I ask later I want to generalise to multiple co-ordinate systems:

First, I set up a separable function `f[]`

```
f[r_, θ_, t_] := R[r] Θ[θ] T[t]
```

Then I set up the wave equation:

```
WaveEqn = Laplacian[f[r, θ, t], {r, θ}, "Polar"] ==
    1/c^2  D[f[r, θ, t], {t, 2}] // Simplify // Expand
```

... where the `// Simplify // Expand` at the end makes it all look nice and clean.

Now I split the equation at the equals sign:

```
{lhs, rhs} = {WaveEqn[[1]]/f[r, θ, t] // Simplify // Expand,
              WaveEqn[[2]]/f[r, θ, t] // Simplify // Expand}
```

Yes, I know I could have done this directly instead of making `WaveEqn` an equation; bear with me.

Now I tidy up the LHS and introduce `k1^2`, the constant of separation. This will give me an equation that I want to separate like the `{lhs,hrs}` above, except that `\Theta[]` and `R[]` will both be on the LHS. **What I really want is** `r`, `R[]` and its derivatives on the LHS, and `θ`, `Θ[]` and its derivatives on the RHS. The `r^2` factor is a hack to clean up the terms:

```
eqn1 = r^2 (lhs - k1^2) == 0 // Expand
```

**And now the question**. I did `eqn11` and `eqn12` below by hand by copy/pasting bits from the evaluation of `eqn1`, and using `k2^2` as the constant of separation. How can I do this automagically? Maple's `collect()` operation does a pretty good job, but I now want to do this in Mathematica:

```
eqn11 = R[r] (-k1^2 r^2 +
    (r Derivative[1][R][r])/R[r] +
        (r^2 R^′′[r])/R[r] - k2^2)
    == 0 // Simplify // Expand

eqn12 = Θ[θ]((Θ^′′)[θ]/Θ[θ]
    - k2^2)
    == 0 // Simplify // Expand
```

This was easy, as its part of the first split:

```
eqn2 = rhs - k1^2 == 0 // Simplify // Expand
```

Now solve everything. I include this for completeness; its not part of the actual question:

```
DSolve[eqn11, R[r], r]
DSolve[eqn12, Θ[θ], θ]
DSolve[eqn2, T[t], t]
```

Comment: Closely related: [Symbolic solution(s) to generalized Heat equation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55546/245).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is how to get `eqn11` and `eqn12` automatically, introducing the additional separation constant `k2^2`. Here is one way of doing it:

```
eqn11 = 
 Expand@Simplify[(Select[
     Apply[Subtract, eqn1], (D[#, θ] == 0 &)]) == k2^2]
```

> $$-\text{k1}^2 r^2+\frac{r^2 R''(r)}{R(r)}+\frac{r
>    R'(r)}{R(r)}=\text{k2}^2$$

```
eqn12 = 
 Expand@Simplify[(Select[
     Apply[Subtract, eqn1], (D[#, θ] =!= 0 &)]) == -k2^2]
```

> $$\frac{\Theta ''(\theta )}{\Theta (\theta )}+\text{k2}^2=0$$

By applying `Subtract` to `eqn1`, I first bring all terms into one expression. Then I use `Select` to get the terms depending only on one of the variables each. The resulting expressions are then set equal to the  common constant `k2^2`.

Comment: That works very well for `[CapitalTheta][]` and `R[]`, thanks!

How do I include `[Theta]` and `r`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "include"? I don't see where else they should appear.

Comment: In a more general situation, where I don't play tricks by multiplying by `r^2`when creating `eqn1`, I'd like to be able to (say) put `r`, `R`, `R'`, `R''` ... etc on one side and all the equivalent `[Theta]`'s on the other.

Comment: I think that will lead back to what I did in my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55580/245). I.e., divide by `f` and apply the same tricks as above to get the first separation.

Comment: Didn't work. I removed my 'multiply by `r^2`' hack and got an `r` below the line on `eqn12`.

Comment: What you want is probably this: `eqn1=Simplify[lhs==k1^2,r>0]//Expand`. The `r^2` is eliminated automatically that way.

Comment: Yup! That did it! Things are a lot cleaner now, thanks for the answers!