# NDSolve Inconsistent equation dimensions

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I am getting an error while trying to solve for a differential equation. It is saying "NDSolveValue::femper: PDE parsing error... Inconsistant equation dimensions." I was wondering if anyone could help me out figuring what I did wrong. My domain is a prism, and I want to maintain a constant temperature on one of the faces, have the entire prism be that temperature at time = 0, and also has a symmetry boundary. The last faces I will put convective heat transfer through. Sorry if this is a bit hard to visualize through text.

```
HeatTransferModel[T_, X_List, k_, ρ_, Cp_, Velocity_, Source_] :=
  Module[{V, Q, a = k}, 
  V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 
    0, ρ*Cp*Velocity.Inactive[Grad][T, X]];
  Q = If[Source === "NoSource", 0, Source];
  If[FreeQ[a, _?VectorQ], a = a*IdentityMatrix[Length[X]]];
  If[VectorQ[a], a = DiagonalMatrix[a]];
  (*Note the-sign in the operator*)
  a = PiecewiseExpand[Piecewise[{{-a, True}}]];
  Inactive[Div][a.Inactive[Grad][T, X], X] + V - Q]
TimeHeatTransferModel[T_, TimeVar_, X_List, k_, ρ_, Cp_, 
  Velocity_, Source_] := ρ*Cp*D[T, {TimeVar, 1}] + 
  HeatTransferModel[T, X, k, ρ, Cp, Velocity, Source]
```

above is the PDE function, below is remainder of the code

```
length = 0.3;

plastic = 
  Prism[{{0.1335, 0, 0.1585}, {0.15, 0, 0.1415}, {0.15, 0, 
     0.1585}, {0.1335, length, 0.1585}, {0.15, length, 0.1415}, {0.15,
      length, 0.1585}}];

mesh = MeshRegion[plastic, PlotTheme -> "Lines"]; 
 GraphSurfaceMesh[{mesh}]

Subscript[T, hot] = 200;
h = 150;

Subscript[\[Rho], polystyrene] = 1045;
Subscript[Cp, polystyrene] = 1.25;
Subscript[k, polystyrene] = 0.14; 

(* boundary conditions *) 
Subscript[Γ, 
   temp] = {DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y, z] == Subscript[T, hot], 
    y >= length ]};
Subscript[Γ, symmetry] = {NeumannValue[0, x == 0.15]};
Subscript[Γ, 
   convective] = {NeumannValue[h*(Subscript[T, cold] - T[t, x, y, z]),
     z == 0.1585]};
Subscript[Γ, 
   convective1] = {NeumannValue[
    h*(Subscript[T, cold] - T[t, x, y, z]), 
    InfinitePlane[{0.1335, 0, 0.1585}, {0.15, length, 0.1415}, {0.15, 
      0, 0.1415}]]};

ic = {T[0, x, y, z] == Subscript[T, hot]};
parameters = {ρ -> Subscript[ρ, polystyrene], 
   Cp -> Subscript[Cp, polystyrene], k -> Subscript[k, polystyrene]};

tend = 30; (* s *)
pde = {TimeHeatTransferModel[T[t, x, y, z], t, {x, y, z}, k, ρ, 
     Cp, "NoFlow", "NoSource"] == 
    Subscript[Γ, symmetry] + 
     Subscript[Γ, convective] + 
     Subscript[Γ, convective1], 
   Subscript[Γ, temp], ic} /. parameters;
measure = 
  AbsoluteTiming[
   MaxMemoryUsed[
     Monitor[Tfun = 
       NDSolveValue[pde, T, {t, 0, tend}, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, 
        EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])], 
      monitor]]/(1024.^2)];
Print["Time -> ", measure[[1]], "\nMemory -> ", measure[[2]]]
```

Comment: $length$ is not defined.   I could not find `GraphSurfaceMesh` in the documentation.  You probably should be using `ToElementMesh` to creates meshes to be solved by NDSolve.

Comment: You are also missing the polystyrene parameters.

Comment: Perhaps h=length. I even have no found GraphSurfaceMesh on the internet. InfinitePlane wants the triple as a List. The list {x,y,z} in the pde causes problems. The indexed variables in the boundary condition do not work that way. NDSolve requires [values, Reals. Values for the plastics are missing. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55546/symbolic-solutions-to-generalized-heat-equation] might be helpful.

Comment: sorry guys, I forgot to copy and paste those parts of the code, give me a second to edit the post

Comment: ok I have added them. Also I did try to use ToELementMesh but it was not showing up, which is why I used GraphSurfaceMesh. I found that here under applications: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion.html

Comment: To use `ToElementMesh` you must load the package Needs["NDSolve\`FEM`"] first.

Comment: @kmulc  are the strong forms with BCs possible in your post?

Comment: Your code does not produce the error indicated (I get `NDSolveValue::dvnoarg: The function T appears with no arguments.`).  Please post the correct code.

Comment: See point 3 of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999 ("Avoid using subscripted symbols in your code").  It's why I got a confusing error (see previous comment).  Because of such confusions, I often just skip any question that uses `Subscript[..]` for variables.

Answer (score 3):

There were a couple missing/faulty definitions.  Namely, $T_{cold}$ and the heat capacity of polystyrene should be 1000x larger at that density.  Also note that the parentheses should have been removed from the `NeumannValue` specification and that a zero flux is the default setting.

After making those modification, you can use the `BoundaryElementMarkerUnion` property of the mesh to find the element and point markers assigned to the boundaries for easier boundary condition assignment.

Here is a possible workflow:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
length = 0.3
ρpolystyrene = 1045;
Cppolystyrene = 1250;
kpolystyrene = 0.14;
Thot = 200;
Tcold = 20;
h = 150;
tend = 100;
plastic = 
  Prism[{{0.1335, 0, 0.1585}, {0.15, 0, 0.1415}, {0.15, 0, 
     0.1585}, {0.1335, length, 0.1585}, {0.15, length, 0.1415}, {0.15,
      length, 0.1585}}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[plastic, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.000002, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00008];
(* Visualize Boundary Markers for easier BC Assignment *)
groups = mesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"]
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]]
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors, 
  Axes -> True]]
(*boundary conditions*)
Γtemp = {DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y, z] == Thot, 
    ElementMarker == 2]};
(* Zero Flux is the default Neumann Condition *)
(*Subscript[Γ,symmetry]={NeumannValue[0,x\[Equal]0.15]};\
*)
Γconvective = 
  NeumannValue[h*(Tcold - T[t, x, y, z]), ElementMarker == 5];
Γconvective1 = 
  NeumannValue[h*(Tcold - T[t, x, y, z]), ElementMarker == 4];

ic = {T[0, x, y, z] == Thot};
parameters = {ρ -> ρpolystyrene, Cp -> Cppolystyrene, 
   k -> kpolystyrene};

(*s*)pde = {TimeHeatTransferModel[T[t, x, y, z], t, {x, y, z}, 
      k, ρ, Cp, "NoFlow", 
      "NoSource"] ==(*Subscript[Γ,
     symmetry]+*)Γconvective + \
Γconvective1, Γtemp, ic} /. parameters;
measure = 
  AbsoluteTiming[
   MaxMemoryUsed[
     Monitor[Tfun = 
       NDSolveValue[pde, T, {t, 0, tend}, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, 
        EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])], 
      monitor]]/(1024.^2)];
Print["Time -> ", measure[[1]], "\nMemory -> ", measure[[2]]]
```

[image: Mesh]

## Visualization

One could use [`SliceContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html) to view several clip planes of the solution as it evolves over time.

```
uRange = MinMax[Tfun["ValuesOnGrid"]];
frames = Table[
   Rasterize@
    SliceContourPlot3D[
     Tfun[t, x, y, z], {y == 0, y == length, x == 0.15, 
      z == 0.1585, {"YStackedPlanes", 2}}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
     PlotRange -> uRange, 
     ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", uRange}], 
     ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5`], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     Contours -> 15, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 50, 
     MaxRecursion -> 4, 
     ViewPoint -> {-0.36984446450781705`, 
       0.7256633889310892`, -3.284300186955811`}, 
     ViewVertical -> {-0.03520209233494262`, 
       0.9145566012946781`, -0.40292311391079266`}, 
     PlotLegends -> Automatic], {t, tend/10, tend, 2}];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image: Solution animation]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your code but I am getting this error "NDSolveValue::femper: PDE parsing error of {{1306.25 T$188889-NeumannValue[150 (20+Times[<<2>>]),ElementMarker==4]-NeumannValue[150 (20+Times[<<2>>]),ElementMarker==5]}}. Inconsistent equation dimensions. " I would like to get it fixed so that I can visualize it like you said

Comment: @kmulc I started a new _Mathematica_ session and copied the code for `HeatTransferModel` from your question and the code from my answer and it runs.  I am using `"12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"`.  You may want to `Clear` variables or close out and restart _Mathematica_.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you so much!