# Analytical Solution in Generalized Heat Equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, heat-equation

Given the following problem
$$u_{t}-\frac{v}{2}\cdot u_{xx}+\frac{v}{2}\cdot x^2 \cdot u(x)=0 $$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$

Where  $ f(x)=y_1(x)+0.2y_4(x)+0.01y_6 (x) $

$y_n$ are the Eigenfunctions that defined as $ y_n(x)=\exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x) $

By separation we assume $$u(x,t)=X(x)T(x)$$

I have found that the general solution of $T$ is
$T(x)=c_1e^{-\lambda v t}$
and the general solution of $X$ is
$ X_n(x)=\exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x) $

So the general solution to our initial problem is
$u_n(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x) c_1e^{-\lambda v t}$

Using the I.C we got $$ u(x,0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x)=f(x) $$

I found the numerical solution with the following code.

```
eigen[n_] := n + 1/2
Her[n_] := HermiteH[n, x]
Y[n_] := Exp[-x^2/2]*Her[n]
Y[1]
Y[4]
Y[6]
f[x_] = Y[1] + 0.2 Y[4] + 0.01 Y[6]
IC = u[x, 0] == f[x]
PDE = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[x, t]\)\) - 1/2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\(u[x, t]\)\) + 
   1/2*x^2*u[x, t] == 0
BCs = {u[-21, t] == 0, u[21, t] == 0}
sol = First[NDSolve[{PDE, BCs, IC}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -21, 21}]]
Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -21, 21}]
```

[image]
**Update**

Could anyone help me with the code?

```
(* Define the Eigenfunctions *)
y[n_, x_] := Exp[-x^2/2] HermiteH[n, x]
(* Define the constant *)
v = 1;
(* Find the general solution for T *)
T[x_, t_] := c1 Exp[-v \[Lambda] t]
(* Find the general solution for X *)
X[n_, x_] := y[n, x]
(* Combine to get the general solution for u *)
u[n_, x_, t_] := X[n, x] T[x, t]
(* Define the initial condition *)
f[x_] := y[1, x] + 0.2 y[4, x] + 0.01 y[6, x]
(* Solve for the coefficients *)
An[n_] := (Integrate[f[x] X[n, x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]) / (Integrate[X[n, x]^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}])
(* Define the analytical solution *)
u[x_, t_] := Sum[An[n] X[n, x] T[x, t], {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]
(* Plot the solution for t=0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 *)
Plot[{u[x, 0], u[x, 0.1], u[x, 0.2], u[x, 0.3]},{x, -5, 5},PlotRange -> Al]
```

Comment: does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55546/symbolic-solutions-to-generalized-heat-equation) relate your question?

Comment: It can't solve the general heat pde because it is very hard to find symbolic solution to the eigenvalues to the spatial ode $X(x)$. Numerically it is possible to find eigenvalues, but not symbolically. Try `DEigensystem` on `X[x]` ode and you will see that it can't solve it.

Comment: @Nasser so how can I calculate the analytical solution?

Comment: @xzczd How could I involve integrate?

Comment: @xzczd  I mean How could I write this code? I don't quite understand it.

Comment: Never mind, seems that I forgot to clear some of the variables. `DSolve` doesn't seem to be able to handle the problem directly.

Comment: @xzczd if we Apply the solution representation formula to find the solution to the problem with the initial condition f(x). Do you think it will work?

Comment: You mean you want to seek for the $A_n$ in the (assumed) general solution? If you just need the numeric value for the first few terms, it may worth trying, but analytic general formula for $A_n$ is probably too hard. (I sincerely hope I'm wrong. )

Comment: @xzczd Exactly that is my purpose. Because I want to compare the analytical and numerical solution on the same plot

Comment: @Nasser Please could you take a look to the analytical solution that I have written?

Comment: You can't plot this solution using the code you wrote as it has unknowns $c_1$ and $\lambda$.  It is better to make a new specific question instead of keep adding more questions to the same question as it is getting confusing to follow what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!

The issue was that BC must be $\pm \infty$ and the correct normalization needed to be used. Similar to what was done for your generalized wave pde question [Difficulty to Solve the Generalized Wave Equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282961/difficulty-to-solve-the-generalized-wave-equation)

The analytical solution to the general heat pde in 1D

\begin{align*}
u_{t}+\frac{v}{2}x^{2}u &  =\frac{v}{2}u_{xx}\\
u\left(  x,0\right)   &  =f\left(  x\right)  =e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{1}\left(
x\right)  +\frac{1}{5}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{4}\left(  x\right)  +\frac
{1}{100}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{6}\left(  x\right)  \\
u\left(  -\infty,t\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  +\infty,t\right)   &  =0
\end{align*}

is the following

$$
u(x,t)=e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\left(  e^{-\frac{v}{2}3t}H_{1}\left(  x\right)
+\frac{1}{5}e^{-\frac{v}{2}9t}H_{4}\left(  x\right)  +\frac{1}{100}%
e^{-\frac{v}{2}13t}H_{6}\left(  x\right)  \right)
$$

### Animation

[image]

### Code for the above

```
ClearAll[x, t];
v = 1;
sol[x_, t_] := Exp[-x^2/2]*(Exp[-v/2*3*t]*HermiteH[1, x] + 
   1/5*Exp[-v/2*9*t]*HermiteH[4, x] + 1/100*Exp[-v/2*13*t]*HermiteH[6, x])

Y[n_] := Exp[-x^2/2]*HermiteH[n, x]
ic    = u[x, 0] == Y[1] + 0.2 Y[4] + 0.01 Y[6]
pde   = D[u[x, t], t] + v/2*x^2*u[x, t] == v/2*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
L     = 10; (*for NDSolve only*)
bc    = {u[-L, t] == 0, u[L, t] == 0}
nsol  = NDSolveValue[{pde, ic, bc}, u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, 3}];

Manipulate[
 Grid[{{Plot[sol[x0, t0], {x0, -10, 10}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
      PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-4, 4}}, ImageSize -> 300, 
     PlotLabel -> "Analytical"]},
   {Plot[Evaluate[nsol[x0, t0]], {x0, -10, 10}, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-4, 4}}, 
     ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> "Numerical"]
    }}],
 {{t0, 0, "time"}, 0, 3, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ContinuousAction -> True}, TrackedSymbols :> {t0}]
```

### Hand solution

\begin{align*}
u_{t}+\frac{v}{2}x^{2}u &  =\frac{v}{2}u_{xx}\\
u\left(  x,0\right)   &  =f\left(  x\right)  =e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{1}\left(
x\right)  +\frac{1}{5}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{4}\left(  x\right)  +\frac
{1}{100}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{6}\left(  x\right)  \\
u\left(  -\infty,t\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  +\infty,t\right)   &  =0
\end{align*}
Let $u=X\left(  x\right)  T\left(  t\right)  $, then the pde becomes
\begin{align*}
T^{\prime}X+\frac{v}{2}x^{2}XT &  =\frac{v}{2}X^{\prime\prime}T\\
\frac{T^{\prime}}{T}+\frac{v}{2}x^{2} &  =\frac{v}{2}\frac{X^{\prime\prime}%
}{X}\\
\frac{2}{v}\frac{T^{\prime}}{T} &  =\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}-x^{2}%
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{v}\frac{T^{\prime}}{T} &  =-\lambda\\
T^{\prime}+\frac{v}{2}\lambda T &  =0
\end{align*}
The solution to the above is
$$
T=Ae^{-\frac{v}{2}\lambda t}%
$$
And
\begin{align*}
\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}-x^{2} &  =-\lambda\\
-X^{\prime\prime}+x^{2}X &  =\lambda X\\
X\left(  -\infty\right)   &  =0\\
X\left(  \infty\right)   &  =0
\end{align*}
The eigenvalues are (see below) $\lambda_{n}=1+2n$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$.
Hence $\lambda_{n}=\left\{  1,3,5,7,\cdots\right\}  $ and corresponding
eigenfunction are
\begin{align*}
X_{n} &  =e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{n}\left(  x\right)  \qquad n=0,1,2,3\cdots\\
\lambda_{n} &  =\left\{  1,3,5,7,\cdots\right\}
\end{align*}
Hence the pde solution is linear combination of the solutions $X_{n}T_{n}$ or
\begin{align}
u &  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}T_{n}X_{n}\tag{1}\\
&  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}e^{-\frac{v}{2}\lambda_{n}t}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}%
}H_{n}\left(  x\right)  \nonumber
\end{align}
At $t=0$ the above becomes, since $u\left(  x,0\right)  =f\left(  x\right)
=e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{1}\left(  x\right)  +\frac{1}{5}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}%
}H_{4}\left(  x\right)  +\frac{1}{100}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{6}\left(
x\right)  $%
\begin{align*}
e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{1}\left(  x\right)  +\frac{1}{5}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}%
}H_{4}\left(  x\right)  +\frac{1}{100}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{6}\left(
x\right)   &  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{n}\left(
x\right)  \\
e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\left(  H_{1}\left(  x\right)  +\frac{1}{5}H_{4}\left(
x\right)  +\frac{1}{100}H_{6}\left(  x\right)  \right)   &  =\sum
_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{n}\left(  x\right)  \\
e^{-x^{2}}\left(  H_{1}\left(  x\right)  +\frac{1}{5}H_{4}\left(  x\right)
+\frac{1}{100}H_{6}\left(  x\right)  \right)   &  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
A_{n}e^{-x^{2}}H_{n}\left(  x\right)
\end{align*}

multiplying both sides by arbitrary $H_{m}\left(  x\right)  $

$$
e^{-x^{2}}H_{m}\left(  x\right)  \left(  H_{1}\left(  x\right)  +\frac{1}%
{5}H_{4}\left(  x\right)  +\frac{1}{100}H_{6}\left(  x\right)  \right)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}e^{-x^{2}}H_{n}\left(  x\right)  H_{m}\left(
x\right)
$$

Integrating, and moving the integral into the sum on the RHS gives
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}H_{m}\left(  x\right)  H_{1}\left(  x\right)
dx+\frac{1}{5}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}H_{m}\left(  x\right)
H_{4}\left(  x\right)  dx+\frac{1}{100}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}%
H_{m}\left(  x\right)  H_{6}\left(  x\right)  dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}H_{n}\left(  x\right)  H_{m}\left(  x\right)
dx
$$
By orthogonality $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}H_{n}\left(  x\right)
H_{m}\left(  x\right)  dx=\sqrt{\pi}2^{m}m!\delta_{nm}$ (see Wikipedia) hence the above becomes

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}H_{m}\left(  x\right)  H_{1}\left(  x\right)
dx+\frac{1}{5}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}H_{m}\left(  x\right)
H_{4}\left(  x\right)  dx+\frac{1}{100}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}%
H_{m}\left(  x\right)  H_{6}\left(  x\right)  dx  & =A_{m}\sqrt{\pi}2^{m}m!\\
\sqrt{\pi}2\delta_{n,1}+\frac{1}{5}\left(  \sqrt{\pi}2^{4}4!\right)
\delta_{n,4}+\frac{1}{100}\left(  \sqrt{\pi}2^{6}6!\right)  \delta_{n,6}  &
=A_{n}\sqrt{\pi}2^{n}n!
\end{align*}

Hence
\begin{align*}
A_{n}  & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}2^{n}n!}\left(  \sqrt{\pi}2\delta_{n,1}+\frac
{1}{5}\left(  \sqrt{\pi}2^{4}4!\right)  \delta_{n,4}+\frac{1}{100}\left(
\sqrt{\pi}2^{6}6!\right)  \delta_{n,6}\right)
\end{align*}

Therefore the solution (1) becomes
\begin{align}
u\left(  x,t\right)    & =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}e^{-\frac{v}{2}\left(
2n+1\right)  t}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{n}\left(  x\right)  \tag{2}\\
& =A_{1}e^{-\frac{v}{2}\left(  2+1\right)  t}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{1}\left(
x\right)  +A_{4}e^{-\frac{v}{2}\left(  8+1\right)  t}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}
H_{4}\left(  x\right)  +A_{6}e^{-\frac{v}{2}\left(  12+1\right)  t}
e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{6}\left(  x\right)  \\
& =e^{-\frac{v}{2}3t}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{1}\left(  x\right)  +\frac{1}
{5}e^{-\frac{v}{2}9t}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{4}\left(  x\right)  +\frac{1}
{100}e^{-\frac{v}{2}13t}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{6}\left(  x\right) 
\end{align}

Therefore
$$
\boxed{
u(x,t)=e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\left(  e^{-\frac{v}{2}3t}H_{1}\left(  x\right)
+\frac{1}{5}e^{-\frac{v}{2}9t}H_{4}\left(  x\right)  +\frac{1}{100}
e^{-\frac{v}{2}13t}H_{6}\left(  x\right)  \right)
}
$$

### Attempt with DSolve

```
ClearAll[x, t, n];
Y[n_] := Exp[-x^2/2]*HermiteH[n, x]
v = 1;
ic = u[x, 0] == Y[1] + 0.2 Y[4] + 0.01 Y[6]
pde = D[u[x, t], t] + v/2*x^2*u[x, t] == v/2*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
bc = {u[-Infinity, t] == 0, u[Infinity, t] == 0}
sol = DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

No solution.

Comment: Thank you very much again

Answer (score 3):

just to add more to the comment, to help show why this is hard to solve analytically using separation of variables.

To solve using separation of variables we must be able to find the eigenvalues of the BVP ode (the spatial ode) which results. But in this case, since the solution to the ode is very complicated and involves special functions, it can not find the eigenvalues.

\begin{align*}
u_{t}+x^{2}u  & =u_{xx}\\
u\left(  x,0\right)    & =f\left(  x\right)  \\
u\left(  0,t\right)    & =0\\
u\left(  L,t\right)    & =0
\end{align*}

Let $u=X\left(  t\right)  T\left(  t\right)  $ then the pde becomes

$$
XT^{\prime}+x^{2}XT-X^{\prime\prime}T=0
$$

Dividing by $XT\neq0$ gives

\begin{align*}
\frac{T^{\prime}}{T}+x^{2}-\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}  & =0\\
\frac{T^{\prime}}{T}  & =\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}-x^{2}
\end{align*}

Hence both are equal to some constant, say $-\lambda$. Therefore

\begin{align*}
\frac{T^{\prime}}{T}  & =-\lambda\\
T^{\prime}+\lambda T  & =0
\end{align*}

Which has the solution

$$
T\left(  t\right)  =c_{1}e^{-\lambda t}
$$

The $X\left(  x\right)  $ ode is now used to determine $\lambda\,$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}-x^{2}  & =-\lambda\\
X\left(  0\right)    & =0\\
X\left(  L\right)    & =0
\end{align*}

And here we see the problem. It is not possible to determine $\lambda_{n}$
values (eigenvalues) which satisfies the BC given and give non zero solution
for the eigenfunction $X_{n}\left(  x\right)  $. The solution to this ode involves `ParabolicCylinderD` and unresolved integrals. So it is a hopeless case to try to tackle this analytically. `DEigensystem` can't do it. But numerically it can find eigenvalues and corresponsing eigenfunctions.

```
 NDEigensystem[{X''[x] - x^2*X[x]}, X[x], {x, 0, 10}, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There might be other approaches to solving this analytically (may be via Fourier transform) but I do not see myself a way via separation of variables method.

**Update**
To answer comment about Transform methods for PDE, I think the best book I found on this is

[Transform Methods for Solving Partial Differential Equations (Symbolic and Numeric Computation Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0849373743)

[image]

**Update to answer comment on plot**

You could do the following

[image]

```
eigen[n_] := n + 1/2
Her[n_] := HermiteH[n, x]
Y[n_] := Exp[-x^2/2]*Her[n]
Y[1]
Y[4]
Y[6]
f[x_] = Y[1] + 0.2 Y[4] + 0.01 Y[6]
IC = u[x, 0] == f[x]
PDE = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(t\)]\(u[x, t]\)\) - 1/2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(x, x\)]\(u[x, t]\)\) + 
      1/2*x^2*u[x, t] == 0
BCs = {u[-21, t] == 0, u[21, t] == 0}
sol = First[NDSolve[{PDE, BCs, IC}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -21, 21}]]
Manipulate[
 Plot[u[x, t] /. sol /. t -> t0, {x, -21, 21}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-4, 4}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ,
 {{t0, 0, "time"}, 0, 1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

**Update to make separate snap shots**

```
eigen[n_] := n + 1/2
Her[n_] := HermiteH[n, x]
Y[n_] := Exp[-x^2/2]*Her[n]
Y[1]
Y[4]
Y[6]
f[x_] = Y[1] + 0.2 Y[4] + 0.01 Y[6]
IC = u[x, 0] == f[x]
PDE = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[x, t]\)\) - 1/2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\(u[x, t]\)\) + 
         1/2*x^2*u[x, t] == 0
BCs = {u[-21, t] == 0, u[21, t] == 0}
sol = First[NDSolve[{PDE, BCs, IC}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -21, 21}]]

makePlot[t0_?NumericQ] := Module[{},
  Plot[u[x, t] /. sol /. t -> t0, {x, -21, 21}, 
     PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-4, 4}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
     GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"Solution at t=", t0}]]
  ]
```

And now

```
 makePlot[0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 makePlot[.3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

etc...

Comment: Numerically I think it is correct what I have done!

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos Yes, numerical approach is only practical way to solve this. I did not look/verify your numerical code, I assume it is correct.

Comment: Via Fourier transform what do I have to do? Do I have to write the solution like the Fourier series? $u_n(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x) c_1e^{-\lambda v t}$

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos I mean transform to frequency domain, solve there and invert back. Similar to how we solve an ode using Laplace transform (transform to S space, solve there and invert back). Many examples on the net, see [this](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m267/pdeft.pdf) for example. It is a powerful method to try when separation of variables fail but considered more advanced method. There is a whole book just on using integral transforms for solving pde's.  I do not know if it will work or not on this pde though.

Comment: Oh ok! One last question how can I take three different snapshots from my numerical solution using the command plot?

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos  I do not know how you obtained the eigenfunction there in what you wrote. Mathematica does not give $H_n(x)$ for solution to the $X(x)$ ode, it gives solution using `ParabolicCylinderD`. But you also need to find $\lambda_n$ first? But as you see, Mathematica can't solve this pde analytically due to this.

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos **three different snapshots** not sure what you mean. Why not make 3 different plots at different time $t$? sorry, not following you there.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I mean. Sorry for my English.

Comment: ```fig1 = Plot[u[x, 5], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0, 0, 1], AbsoluteThickness[0.5`]}}] ``` I am trying this but does not work

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos fyi, added a plot command.

Comment: What do I have to change to the above command to work?

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos change? Nothing. The code I used is posted below the plot/Manipulate. It works as is on V 13.2.1. DO you mean you do not want to see the evolution of the solution for the times given and have specific time only? The code is there, feel free to change it as you like.

Comment: I wondered if it is possible to make three different plots but I think and this is ok

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos sure. Will add that also.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate all your help

Comment: I figured out how to solve the problem numerically. Could it be solved analytically if we apply the solution representation formula to find the solution to the problem with the initial condition f(x)?

Comment: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2856871?p_p_auth=KOENJex6 This is what I have done