# Plot Generalized Heat Equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

Given the following problem
$$u_{t}-\frac{v}{2}\cdot u_{xx}+\frac{v}{2}\cdot x^2 \cdot u(x)=0 $$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$

Where  $ f(x)=y_1(x)+0.2y_4(x)+0.01y_6 (x) $

$y_n$ are the Eigenfunctions that defined as $ y_n(x)=\exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x) $

By separation we assume $$u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$$

$$\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=v (\frac{1}{2} \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}-\frac{x^2}{2})=-\lambda$$

So we have

$$T'(x)=-\lambda v T(x)$$

I have found that the general solution of $T$ is
$T(x)=c_1e^{-\lambda v t}$
and for
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}-\frac{x^2}{2}=-\lambda$$
which gives
$$-\frac{1}{2}X''(x)+\frac{x^2}{2}X(x)=\lambda X(x)$$

the general solution of $X$ is
$ X_n(x)=\exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x) $

So the general solution to our initial problem is
$u_n(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x) c_1e^{-\lambda v t}$

Using the I.C we got $$ u(x,0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x)=f(x) $$

I found an analytical solution with the following code.

```
f[x_]:=Exp[-x^2/2] (1+0.2*HermiteH[4,x]+0.01*HermiteH[6,x])
n=10;
 A=Table[1/(Sqrt[Pi] 2^m m!) Integrate[f[x] HermiteH[m,x] Exp[x^2/2],{x,0,1}],{m,1,n}];
u[x_,t_]:=Sum[A[[m]] Exp[-m/2 t] Exp[-x^2/2] HermiteH[m-1,x],{m,1,n}]
 Plot[{u[x,0],u[x,0.3],u[x,0.7]},{x,-20,20},PlotRange->All,PlotLegends->{"t=0","t=0.3","t=0.7"}]
 fig1=Plot3D[u[x,t], {t,0,10},{x,-21,21},PlotRange->All,ColorFunction->"BlueGreenYellow"]
```

[image]
[image]

I tried also to write the following code, thus I could compare which one gives me better results but it does not seem to work

```
(* Define the Eigenfunctions *)
y[n_, x_] := Exp[-x^2/2] HermiteH[n, x]
(* Define the constant *)
v = 1;
(* Find the general solution for T *)
T[x_, t_] := c1 Exp[-v \[Lambda] t]
(* Find the general solution for X *)
X[n_, x_] := y[n, x]
(* Combine to get the general solution for u *)
u[n_, x_, t_] := X[n, x] T[x, t]
(* Define the initial condition *)
f[x_] := y[1, x] + 0.2 y[4, x] + 0.01 y[6, x]
(* Solve for the coefficients *)
An[n_] := (Integrate[f[x] X[n, x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]) / (Integrate[X[n, x]^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}])
(* Define the analytical solution *)
u[x_, t_] := Sum[An[n] X[n, x] T[x, t], {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]
(* Plot the solution for t=0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 *)
Plot[{u[x, 0], u[x, 0.1], u[x, 0.2], u[x, 0.3]},{x, -5, 5},PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Your "general  solution Xn" doesn't solve  the ode `Xn''[x]==(x^2-n) Xn[x]`I think!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann the general solution is $ X_n(x)=\exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x) $

Comment: That's understood. But this `Xn` should solve  `Xn''[x]==(x^2-n) Xn[x]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann So do you mean that I have written wrong the command in the second case? I am asking because I am a bit confused

Comment: You tried to solve your pde with method separation of variables, but didn't show the two separated ode's. If I'm not wrong the  x- ode should be   `X''[x]==(x^2-lamda) X[x] ` and the time-ode should be `T'[t]== -lambda v/2 T`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I have updated my question, with the steps how I found the general solutions

Comment: I tried `DSolve[X''[x] == (x^2 - 2 lambda) X[x], X, x] // 
 Simplify[#, lambda > 0] &` and got a different general solution in Mathematica v12.2.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann
This is given from a previous question. If we find an expression like $-\frac{1}{2}X''(x)+\frac{x^2}{2}X(x)=\lambda X(x)$ the eigenfunctions defined as $ y_n(x)=\exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x) $ for this reason we use Hemite Polynomials with their properties

Comment: I don't know this previous question, but `DSolve` should find this magic general solution too!

Comment: First, a note about your questions. **Please** do not post same questions here and on community forum. It is OK to do this if you also include a link to each forum saying you cross posted the question. This way people do not waste time asking and answering same thing without knowing what is going on at the other site(s). I noticed you do this all the time with your same questions posted here and at community without any mention of this double posted.

Comment: Now about your $X_n(x)$ solution. This is an eigenvalue BVP ode. Not a normal ode. i.e. you can't just use DSolve to solve it. It will not work. You need to use `DEigensystem` to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions. As mentioned in the answer to your question [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282594/analytical-solution-in-generalized-heat-equation](analytical-solution-in-generalized-heat-equation) it is not possible to analytically solve this eigenvalue BVP to find the eigenvalues $\lambda$. But can be done numerically.

Comment: Third, in separation of variable, no need to add a constant $c_1$ to the $T(t)$ solution as that is absorbed by the one that comes from the remaining constant from the $X_n(x)$ solution (if you can find it).  For the ode $X_n(x)$ there are **THREE** unknowns. The two standard constants of integrations (since second order) and $\lambda$. In solving eigenvalue BVP with 2 BC, one constant is eliminated, then $\lambda_n$ is found such that $X_n(x)$ does not vanish, and hence what remains is just ONE $c_n$ constant which is unknown. Now you use initial conditions to find this $c_n$

Comment: ref the plot: **but it does not seem to work** I mentioned why that is yesterday in your other question [analytical-solution-in-generalized-heat-equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282594/analytical-solution-in-generalized-heat-equation) The plot command you show does not work because you have $c_1$ and $\lambda$ unknowns in what you are trying to plot, and hence Plot will give empty plot. When plotting, all parameters need to have numerical values.

Comment: @Nasser ok! I am not going to do that again! I am sorry

Comment: fyi, this [page](https://12000.org/my_notes/boundary_values/report.htm)  shows how to solve eigenvalue BVP for all possible homogeneous BC's for one standard second order ode. You will have to do the same for the $X(x)$ ode above. But because your ode is much harder, this makes it not possible to do analytically. But it is the same logic that needs to be applied.

Comment: @Nasser Oh!Perfect!! I will study them

Answer (score 1):

Here is 3D plot, analytical vs. numerical, using solution given in [Analytical Solution in Generalized Heat Equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282594/analytical-solution-in-generalized-heat-equation)

[image]

### Code

```
ClearAll[x, t,n];
v = 1;
sol[x_, t_] := 
 Exp[-x^2/2]*(Exp[-v/2*3*t]*HermiteH[1, x] + 
    1/5*Exp[-v/2*9*t]*HermiteH[4, x] + 
    1/100*Exp[-v/2*13*t]*HermiteH[6, x])
Y[n_] := Exp[-x^2/2]*HermiteH[n, x]
ic = u[x, 0] == Y[1] + 0.2 Y[4] + 0.01 Y[6]
pde = D[u[x, t], t] + v/2*x^2*u[x, t] == v/2*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
L = 10; (*for NDSolve only*)
bc = {u[-L, t] == 0, u[L, t] == 0}
nsol = NDSolveValue[{pde, ic, bc}, u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, 3}];

Manipulate[
 Module[{t},
  Grid[{{Plot3D[Evaluate@sol[x, t0], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, t0}, 
      PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 2}, {-2, 2}},
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
      PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-4, 4}},
      ImageSize -> 300,
      PlotLabel -> "Analytical",
      AxesLabel -> {"x", "time", "u(x,t)"},
      BaseStyle -> 14]}
    ,
    {Plot3D[Evaluate@nsol[x, t0], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, t0}, 
      PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 2}, {-2, 2}},
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
      PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-4, 4}},
      ImageSize -> 300,
      PlotLabel -> "Numerical",
      AxesLabel -> {"x", "time", "u(x,t)"},
      BaseStyle -> 14]}
    }]
  ],
 {{t0, 0.01, "time"}, 0.01, 2, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ContinuousAction -> True}, TrackedSymbols :> {t0}]
```

And

```
Plot3D[sol[x, t], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, 6}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 6}, {-4, 4}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]