# Difficulty to Solve the Generalized Wave Equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

Given the following problem
$$u_{tt}-\frac{v}{2}\cdot u_{xx}+\frac{v}{2}\cdot x^2 \cdot u(x)=0 $$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$
$$u_t(x,0)=g(x)=0$$
Where  $ f(x)=y_0(x) $

$y_n$ are the Eigenfunctions that defined as $ y_n(x)=\exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x) $

By separation we assume $$u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$$

$$\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)}=v (\frac{1}{2} \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}-\frac{x^2}{2})=-\lambda$$

So we have

$$T''(x)=-\lambda v T(x)$$

I have found that the general solution of $T$ is

$T(x)=c_1 \cos{\sqrt{\lambda v}t}+c_2 \sin{\sqrt{\lambda v}t}$

and for
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}-\frac{x^2}{2}=-\lambda$$
which gives
$$-\frac{1}{2}X''(x)+\frac{x^2}{2}X(x)=\lambda X(x)$$

the general solution of $X$ is
$ X_n(x)=\exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x) $ given by our textbook and the eigenvalues are $\lambda_n=n+\frac{1}{2}$

So the general solution to our initial problem is
$u_n(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (A_n \cos{\sqrt{\lambda v}t}+B_n \sin{\sqrt{\lambda v}t}) \exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x)$

Using the I.C we got $$ u(x,0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x)=f(x) $$
To finish our solution, we need to solve the equation for the $A_n.$

To do this, you need to use the orthogonality property of Hermite polynomials:
$$A_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}n!} \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,0) H_n(x) e^{-x^2/2} dx $$

I have solved this problem numerically with the following code

```
Her[n_] := HermiteH[n, x]
Y[n_] := Exp[-x^2/2]*Her[n]
Y[0]
f[x_] = Y[0]
PDE = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t, t\)]\(V[x, t]\)\) - 1/2 \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({x, 2}\)]\(V[x, t]\)\) + 
   1/2*x^2*V[x, t] == 0
BCs = {u[-21, t] == 0, u[21, t] == 0}
IC = u[x, 0] == f[x]
IC2 = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[x, 0]\)\) == 0
sol =
 V /. First[NDSolve[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t, t\)]\(V[x, t]\)\) - 1/2 \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({x, 2}\)]\(V[x, t]\)\) + 
       1/2*x^2*V[x, t] == 0, V[x, 0] == f[x], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(V\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, 0] == 0, 
     V[-21, t] == V[21, t] == 0}, {V}, {t, 0, 20}, {x, -21, 21}, 
    MaxStepSize -> 100000, MaxSteps -> 100000, PrecisionGoal -> 4]]
fig2 = Plot3D[sol[x, t], {t, 0, 10}, {x, -21, 21}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"}][#3] &)]
fig4 = Plot[sol[x, 3], {x, -21, 21}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Dashed, Thick}}]
```

[image]
[image]

Now I have tried to solve it analytically but the following code gave no results! Any suggestions?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Her[n_] := HermiteH[n, x]
Y[n_] := Exp[-x^2/2]*Her[n]
Y[0]
f[x_] = Y[0]
IC = u[x, 0] == f[x]
IC2 = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[x, 0]\)\) == 0
v = 1
\[Omega] = Sqrt[\[Lambda]*v]
U[x_, t_, N_] = \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 
    1\), \(N\)]\(\((a[n]*Cos[\[Omega]*t] + b[n]*Sin[\[Omega]*t])\)*
   HermiteH[n, x]*Exp[\(-x^2\)/2]\)\)
integrand[n_] = f[x]*HermiteH[n, x]*Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2 Pi*n!]
A[n_] = NIntegrate[integrand[n], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
u[x_, t_] = U[x, t, 10]
fig1 = Plot3D[u[x, t], {t, 0, 10}, {x, -21, 21}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
fig3 = Plot[u[x, 3], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0, 0, 1], AbsoluteThickness[0.5`]}}]
```

Comment: I think you are making similar mistake as your last question about the generalized heat pde. You have to determine the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ at one point that go with the eigenfunctions $X_n(x)$. You can't just solve for $A_n$ from initial conditions with  $\lambda_n$  unknown. Did you find these first? Does your book give the eigenvalues? The spatial ode is same as the one you had in your earlier question and I think we agreed that finding analytically the eigenvalues was not possible because the solution is very complicated.

Comment: [analytical-solution-in-generalized-heat-equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282594/analytical-solution-in-generalized-heat-equation)

Comment: @Nasser yes! The eigenvalues are given by $\lambda_n=n+\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Ok, then please add these to the question., I did not see these anywhere. And what are the boundary conditions?

Comment: @Nasser Now could we solve it?

Comment: What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: @Nasser $x \in [-L,L]$ with $L=21$ and 
$u(-21,t)=u(21,t)=0$

Comment: Are you sure these $\lambda_n$ are correct? I just checked with `NDEigenvalues` and they do not agree. You can check and see for yourself. `DEigenvalues` can not solve them analytically as per last question.  Does the book show how they found them? There is something off somewhere. The first 6 eigenvalues I get are `{0.53174, 1.53811, 2.84577, 4.1346, 5.26635, 7.19663}`

Comment: @Nasser $-\frac{1}{2}X''(x)+\frac{x^2}{2}X(x)=EX(x)$ quantum harmonic oscillator eigenvalues  are given fromt the textbook $\lambda_n=n+\frac{1}{2}$ and the eigenfunctions are $X_n=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}H_n(x)$

Comment: @Nasser Is it clearer now what the problem is? Because it's been giving me a hard time

Comment: Ah! I see your error. These eigenvalues are not for the BC you gave. Now I can solve for them using `DEigenvalues` (i.e. analytically) and they match the book.   Will try to write something.

Comment: @Nasser Probably it is the same mistake as the question you have referred to above.

Comment: btw, you should not use `N` for variables in your code. This is builtin symbol. Also the `n!` should not be inside the sqrt, it is outside. See Wikpedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the analytical solution. It now matches the numerical solution.

Few things were corrected including normalization. See [Hermite_polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) for references used to find correct weight. The one used is

[image]

But to use the above, it is $e^{-x^2}$ and not $e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$, this is why the hand solution below makes this adjustment during finding $A_n$.

Without this important change, the analytical solution was not matching the numerical solution. Another important change is that the BC must be $\pm \infty$ and not finite domain. So can  not use $L=21$ for example. This explains why `DEigensystem` could not solve it analytically before but solved instantly when the BC was at$\pm \infty$.

It is important to note that domain length can affect the eigenvalues!  For example using $L=1$ vs. $L=\pi$ one can obtain different eigenvalues.

Notice that `DSolve` is not able to solve this analytically. May be in Version 14.0 it will be able to do that.

```
(*analytical solution *)
ClearAll[x, t, n, sol];
v = 1;
int[n_] := Integrate[Exp[-x^2]*HermiteH[n, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
lam[n_] := 2 n + 1;
sol[max_] := Sum[1/(Sqrt[Pi]*2^n*n!)*int[n]*Cos[Sqrt[v/2*lam[n]]*t]*Exp[-x^2/2]*
    HermiteH[n, x], {n, 0, max, 1}];
```

For example, using 5 terms, the solution is

```
sol[5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is side by side with numerical solution

[image]

### Code

```
ClearAll[x, t, n, sol];
v = 1;
int[n_] := 
 Integrate[Exp[-x^2]*HermiteH[n, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
lam[n_] := 2 n + 1;
sol[max_] := 
  Sum[1/(Sqrt[Pi]*2^n*n!)*int[n]*Cos[Sqrt[v/2*lam[n]]*t]*Exp[-x^2/2]*
    HermiteH[n, x], {n, 0, max, 1}];

L = 10;
bcN = {u[-L, t] == 0, u[L, t] == 0};
ic = u[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2/2];
pde = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] - 1/2 *v*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
    1/2*v*x^2*u[x, t] == 0;

nsol = NDSolveValue[{pde, ic, bcN}, u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, 10}];    

Manipulate[
 Module[{theSolution = sol[10]},
  Row[{
    Plot[Evaluate[theSolution /. {x -> x0, t -> t0}], {x0, -10, 10}, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
     PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1.1, 1.1}}, ImageSize -> 300, 
     PlotLabel -> "Analytical"]
    ,
    Plot[Evaluate[nsol[x0, t0]], {x0, -10, 10}, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
     PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1.1, 1.1}}, ImageSize -> 300, 
     PlotLabel -> "Numerical"]
    }
   ]
  ],
 {{t0, 0, "time"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ContinuousAction -> False},
 TrackedSymbols :> {t0}
 ]
```

### Hand solution

\begin{align*}
u_{tt}+\frac{v}{2}x^{2}u  & =\frac{v}{2}u_{xx}\\
u\left(  x,0\right)    & =f\left(  x\right)  =e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\\
u_{t}\left(  x,0\right)    & =0\\
u\left(  -\infty,t\right)    & =0\\
u\left(  +\infty,t\right)    & =0
\end{align*}
Let $u=X\left(  x\right)  T\left(  t\right)  $, then the pde becomes
\begin{align*}
T^{\prime\prime}X+\frac{v}{2}x^{2}XT  & =\frac{v}{2}X^{\prime\prime}T\\
\frac{T^{\prime\prime}}{T}+\frac{v}{2}x^{2}  & =\frac{v}{2}\frac
{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}\\
\frac{2}{v}\frac{T^{\prime\prime}}{T}  & =\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}-x^{2}%
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{v}\frac{T^{\prime\prime}}{T}  & =-\lambda\\
T^{\prime\prime}+\frac{v}{2}\lambda T  & =0
\end{align*}
The solution to the above is
$$
T=A\cos\left(  \sqrt{\frac{v}{2}\lambda}t\right)  +B\sin\left(  \sqrt{\frac
{v}{2}\lambda}t\right)
$$
And
\begin{align*}
\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}-x^{2}  & =-\lambda\\
-X^{\prime\prime}+x^{2}X  & =\lambda X\\
X\left(  -\infty\right)    & =0\\
X\left(  \infty\right)    & =0
\end{align*}
The eigenvalues are (see below) $\lambda_{n}=1+2n$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$.
Hence $\lambda_{n}=\left\{  1,3,5,7,\cdots\right\}  $ and corresponding
eigenfunction are
\begin{align*}
X_{n}  & =e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{n}\left(  x\right)  \qquad n=0,1,2,3\cdots\\
\lambda_{n}  & =\left\{  1,3,5,7,\cdots\right\}
\end{align*}
Hence the pde solution is linear combination of the solutions $X_{n}T_{n}$ or
\begin{align}
u  & =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}T_{n}X_{n}\tag{1}\\
& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[  A_{n}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\frac{v}{2}\lambda_{n}%
}t\right)  +B_{n}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\frac{v}{2}\lambda_{n}}t\right)  \right]
e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{n}\left(  x\right)  \nonumber
\end{align}
At $t=0$ the above becomes, since $u\left(  x,0\right)  =f\left(  x\right)
=e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}$
\begin{align*}
e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}  & =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}%
H_{n}\left(  x\right)  \\
e^{-x^{2}}  & =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}e^{-x^{2}}H_{n}\left(  x\right)  \\
H_{m}\left(  x\right)  e^{-x^{2}}  & =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}e^{-x^{2}}%
H_{n}\left(  x\right)  H_{m}\left(  x\right)
\end{align*}
Integrating
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H_{m}\left(  x\right)  e^{-x^{2}}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty
}A_{n}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}H_{n}\left(  x\right)  H_{m}\left(
x\right)  dx
$$
By orthogonality  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}H_{n}\left(  x\right)
H_{m}\left(  x\right)  dx=\sqrt{\pi}2^{m}m!\delta_{nm}$ (see Wikipedia) hence
the above becomes
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H_{m}\left(  x\right)  e^{-x^{2}}dx=A_{m}\sqrt{\pi
}2^{m}m!
$$
Therefore
$$
A_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}2^{n}n!}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H_{n}\left(  x\right)
e^{-x^{2}}dx
$$
The solution (1) becomes
\begin{equation}
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[  \left(  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi
}2^{n}n!}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H_{n}\left(  x\right)  e^{-x^{2}}dx\right)
\cos\left(  \sqrt{\frac{v}{2}\lambda_{n}}t\right)  +B_{n}\sin\left(
\sqrt{\frac{v}{2}\lambda_{n}}t\right)  \right]  e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}%
H_{n}\left(  x\right)  \tag{2}%
\end{equation}
Taking time derivative the above becomes
$$
u_{t}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[  -\left(  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}2^{n}n!}%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H_{n}\left(  x\right)  e^{-x^{2}}dx\right)  \sqrt
{\frac{v}{2}\lambda_{n}}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\frac{v}{2}\lambda_{n}}t\right)
+B_{n}\sqrt{\frac{v}{2}\lambda_{n}}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\frac{v}{2}\lambda_{n}%
}t\right)  \right]  e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}H_{n}\left(  x\right)
$$
At $t=0$ and since $u_{t}=0$ simplifies to
$$
0=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_{n}\sqrt{\frac{v}{2}\lambda_{n}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}%
}H_{n}\left(  x\right)
$$
Therefore $B_{n}=0$. The final solution from (2) becomes
$$
\boxed{
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}2^{n}%
n!}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H_{n}\left(  x\right)  e^{-x^{2}}dx\right)
\cos\left(  \sqrt{\frac{v}{2}\lambda_{n}}t\right)  e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}%
H_{n}\left(  x\right)
}
$$
For $\lambda_{n}=\left\{  1,3,5,7,\cdots\right\}  $

### Finding eigenvalues and eigenfunctions

```
ode = -X''[x] + x^2*X[x] == 0
DEigensystem[{First@ode, X[-Infinity] == 0, X[Infinity] == 0}, 
 X[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I assume I have to define again the Pde and the IC. Right?

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos  You just need to use specific value for $L$ when using NDSOlve as it is does accept Infinity as domain length. That is all. I did not change anything else as far as the pde specifications or initial conditions as you can see.

Comment: Ok, I can understand that. I asked that because when I copied the code Numerical solution doesn't appear as it is in this post!! It does not appear at all

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos Ah, I had missing cell, forgot to copy which has the pde and ic, Please try the new code now. It should all be there now.  I had written things in separate cells and when I copied them, forgot one cell.  But they are all the same as you show them in your question. No changes made to these.

Comment: Wow! I tried as $f(x)=E^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} + 1.6 E^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} x$ and there are big differences between analytical and numerical solutions!! Thanks

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos  Because the solution given above is based on IC being `Exp[-x^2/2]` ? Are you comparing the analytical solution given above with the numerical solution when IC is the new one? Ofcourse they will be different. Or may be I misunderstood what you are saying.

Comment: Yes, I compare the new numerical solution with the analytical one! I think the analytical does not change if I change the $f(x)$

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos Ofcourse the analytical solution will change when initial conditions changes.  It affects $A_n$ which depends on what $f(x)$ is. When $A_n$ changes the solution will change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144957/discussion-between-athanasios-paraskevopoulos-and-nasser).